# React Native Component cannot use super

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, super

I've created a component with a few functions for React components that I'd like to use in multiple components.

I've tried implementing it, but whenever I try to call `super.updateHeader`, it crashes with error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:84 Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError:  
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Using `super` in the constructor works without an issue.
Trying to reach the function with `this.updateHeader` results in

```
Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError: this.updateHeader is not a function
```

Neither `updateHeader` nor the function I'm calling it from are arrow functions.

How do I solve this? (They're instance based, so I'd like to stay away from creating some sort of library for this)

SuperComponent:

```
class CustomRouteViewComponent extends Component {
    updateHeader(props) {
        const {settings, navigation} = props;

        props.navigation.setParams({
            headerTintColor: settings.theme === 'dark' ? commonColorDark.textColor : commonColor.textColor,
            backgroundColor: settings.theme === 'dark' ? commonColorDark.headerStyle : commonColor.headerStyle,
        });
    };
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({settings: state.settings});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomRouteViewComponent);
```

HomeScreen

```
class Home extends CustomRouteViewComponent {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.updateHeader(this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Hello!</Text></View>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'creating a library'?

Comment: I mean creating a separate file with all sorts of helper functions

Comment: I've added the basis of the 2 components

Comment: try with `super.updateHeader(this.props);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OOP inheritance is mixed with functional approach (Redux `connect`).  `CustomRouteViewComponent` in `Home` module is connected functional component and not original class component.

`CustomRouteViewComponent` class could be exported for inheritance purposes, or original class could be reached on connected component as:

```
class Home extends CustomRouteViewComponent.WrappedComponent {...}
```

This will result in problems because `CustomRouteViewComponent` already relies on connected props, but its own `mapStateToProps` won't be taken into account, i.e. there won't be `props.settings` in `Home`.

A proper solution is to not mix OOP with functional programming in this case. The behaviour from `CustomRouteViewComponent` could be achieved via HOC or the composition of `mapStateToProps` functions.